# How to: create a heat map of the market

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, heatmap

I am interested in creating a heat map of the stock market using internal data, in much the same way as the following site: http://www.smartmoney.com/map-of-the-market/

We have all the data necessary to do so, as well as a C#/ASP.NET front end and a C#/SQL Server 2005 back end.

Can anyone recommend any resources for creating this type of web application?  P.S. Free is better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a technique called [Treemapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). This is tons of information on how to generate these kinds of graphs online.

Answer (score 0):

The charting tools provided by http://www.anychart.com/ are really good for this.

Heres [some examples of their heat maps](http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Tree-Map-and-Heat-Map-Charts.php). I've used these charts before with ASP.NET and C#. Very easy to use.